# What is the proper Ruby syntax for values in select option form?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that is submitting data to a model with nested attributes. I am using select to choose from a list of options.

The **Articles** model accepts_nested_attributes_for the **Documents** model, which has_attached_file called **Attachment**. The url_path of the attachment is what the select field should be selecting.

How to I change the value of the select field?

The HTML looks like this right now:

```
<select id="article_document" name="article[document]">
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

But I want this:

```
<select id="article_document_url_path" name="article[document][url_path]">
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

The Ruby looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @article, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

    <%= f.select( :document,
              options_for_select(@article.attachment_list.map{ |c| [c, {'data-img-src' => c }] }) ) %>
<% end %>
```

*Rails 4.1.8, ruby 2.1.5p273*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= form_for @article, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :document do |doc|%>
        <%= doc.select(
            :url_path,  
            options_for_select(
                @article.attachment_list.map{ |c| [c, {'data-img-src' => c }] }
            ) 
        ) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```